# How to Update/Edit data in database with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Working on a web app , I just added the below update code and it's not working .
The summary of all the below code is :

- Click a Button called `update`
- It brings out the FORM which should contain the values of the clicked/current product.
- Now when I hit save in this form it should update the database but it is not.
- I am using `$_GET` in PHP file (update.php) to get the current Product `ID`.And then getting all data of that product via that `ID`.

PS: There is no error in console.

**UPDATE CODE:**

```
<?php 
    include "includes/connection.php";
    switch($_GET['action']) {
        case 'update_entry' :
            $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
            $index = $data->id; 
            $productname = $data->pname;
            $company = $data->company;
            $price = $data->price;
            $quantity = $data->quantity;
            if(isset($productname) && !empty($productname) && isset($company) && !empty($company) && isset($price) && !empty($price) && isset($quantity) && !empty($quantity)){
                $query = "UPDATE `product` SET `id`='$index',`name`='$productname',`company`='$company',`price`='$price',`quantity`='$quantity' WHERE id= $index";

                if(mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
                  return true;
                } else {
                  echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br />" . mysqli_error($con);
                }
                break;
            }   
    }
?>
```

**Controller** :

```
myApp.controller("updateCtrl",['$scope','$http','$routeParams','$location',function($scope,$http,$routeParams,$location){
    $scope.update = function(){
         var currentId = $routeParams.id;
         $http.post("update.php?action=update_entry",{'id':currentId})
             .then(function(data){
                $location.path('/viewproduct');
         });
    }
}]);
```

**HTML:**

```
<form style="padding:10px" ng-controller="updateCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ProductName">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.name}}" ng-model="productname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Company </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.company}}" ng-model="company" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Price </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.price}}" ng-model="price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Quantity </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.quantity}}" ng-model="quantity" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="update()">Save updated data</button>
    <a href="#/viewproduct" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
    <h1 ng-if="successMessage == 0">Great Data is Updated!</h1>
</form>
```

Update Button:

```
<td ng-controller="updateCtrl"><a class="btn btn-primary" href="#/updateproduct/action={{product.id}}" >Update</a></td>
```

Comment: Can you see the data in your php? I'm not a PHP-Expert, but you POST the data in Angular and want to GET it in PHP, try $_POST instead maybe. In Addition your contoller does not have a model-object which seems strange as well.

Comment: @FKutsche $_GET is used to get data from URL so I am fetching that specific(current  or clicked) ID and through that ID the data of the clicked product.$_POST is for posting data into something.php .

Comment: Your controller is still using `$http.post` instead of `$http.get`

Comment: @apex-meme-lord I am posting data to update.php not getting.

Comment: You can check the request url and params passed in it, if the params are not passed in the request url there is problem in your angularjs code.

Comment: @SwapnilShende the controller code is available above.

Comment: if this is a web app you can always inspect the request which is sent on clicking the update button. Use the chrome debugger tool.

Comment: @SwapnilShende I already mentioned there is no error in console.

Comment: If your client sends a post request, PHP saves it in `$_POST`.  You can also use `$_REQUEST`, but given key conflicts it will overwrite get parameters (query string).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like below

your view part

```
<form style="padding:10px" ng-controller="updateCtrl">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="ProductName">Product Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.name}}" ng-model="productname" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Company </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.company}}" ng-model="company" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Price </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.price}}" ng-model="price" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="company">Quantity </label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{product.quantity}}" ng-model="quantity" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="update()">Save updated data</button>
    <a href="#/viewproduct" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</a>
    <h1 ng-if="successMessage == 0">Great Data is Updated!</h1>
</form>
<td><a class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="addProductData();" >Update</a></td>
```

Inside your controller do like below

```
$scope.addProductData=function(){
   var updatedata=$.param({'action':'update','productname':$scope.productname,'company':$scope.company,'price':$scope.price,'quantity':$scope.quantity,'id':currentId});
    $http({
            method:'POST',
            url:'update.php',
            data:updatedata,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        }).then(function successCallback(response){
            alert(response.data['msg']);
        },function errorCallback(response) {
            alert(response.data['msg']);
        });
}
```

your `update.php` file should like below.

```
<?php
include "includes/connection.php";
$result=array();
if(isset($_REQUEST["action"]) && $_REQUEST["action"] !=""){
   if($_REQUEST["action"]=="update"){
       $productname = $_POST['productname'];
       $company = $_POST['company'];
      $price = $_POST['price'];
       $quantity = $_POST['quantity'];
     $id=$_POST['id'];

     $query = "UPDATE `product` SET `name`='$productname',`company`='$company',`price`='$price',`quantity`='$quantity' WHERE id= $id";
   if(mysqli_query($con, $query)) {
    $result['msg']="updated successfully";
}else{
   header("HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized");
   $result['msg']="unable to updated";
}
echo json_encode($result);

}
}

?>
```

i think you may basic idea.now you can implement in your way.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `ng-model="{{product.name}}}"` and not the placeholder in HTML.
And in your controller pass that model:

```
$http.post("update.php?action=update_entry",$scope.product)
```

Then you should get some data in your PHP.

Comment: if you pass the data with $http.post then you should get what is in your $scope.product. And adding the product to your ng-model and not the placeholder is where it should be. if you console.log($scope.product); right before http request you can see if there is any data there or not.

Comment: oh and use ng-submit="update()" on the form instead of have it on the button.

Comment: why not in placeholder I want the user to view the data which he wants to edit . And please can you explain what $scope.product will contain ?

Comment: when you connect the product object with ng-model in the html, you can get those values by accessing the $scope.product from the controller.

Comment: The solution works fine. do you want me to teach you why you must use ng-model and $scope or do you want me to make an example for you to try?.. And thanks for the downvote when someone acctualy tries to help.

Comment: I didn't do that buddy , I can't even downvote because my reputation is less then 50.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your php alone to make sure that you can fetch and update data using the php without angular? I would use post as it is more friendly for retrieving and updating data.

I would also b separate your call to the php endpoint into a service (factory). I would also just pass the entire object back through to ensure that you aren't missing something unless you have a concern about bandwidth.

I would unit test php first. Then separate logic in angular. Then b step through in debug to see what's being passed from the view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check this: https://github.com/eliarms/CustomerManagerApp 

This is a simple customer management app using Angularjs and PHP. The goal of the application is to highlight a lot of the different features offered by AngularJS and demonstrate how they can be used together.